# Using boolean result in while loop to display conditional result

Tags: php, boolean

I have a question. I'm using a script that will check the domain in my database. If got a match then it will be `TRUE`.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {       
    echo var_dump($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin'])). " - ". $row['origin'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

`$row['origin']` is an array of domain. Example:

```
test.com
lol.com
what.com
blabla.com
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
bool(false) - test.com.
bool(false) - lol.com.
bool(true) - what.com.
bool(false) - blabla.
```

what.com is in my database so it's a `TRUE`. Now the problem is I don't know how to use/capitalize/exploit (I'm sorry my English is not good) the true result. Is there anyway I could create in the `while` loop:

```
if (bool == true) {
    only echo the true result
}
```

I have did this with associative arrays results. I don't know how to do it `boolean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to find the record that `$phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin'])` returns `true` when passing in the current row of your db query, do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin']) === true) {
        echo var_dump($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin'])). " - " . $row['origin'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Note the `===`, which checks type AND value. `==` is a *falsy* check and therefore could return conditions that evaluate `0 == false` (or `1 == true`) as a true statement(s).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That's a straight forward answer. You a time saver sir. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Please upvote and mark as the answer (with the outlined checkmark next to the answer). `:)`

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot upvote. System give me error: Vote Up requires 15 reputation - Sorry.

Comment: That's ok. SO has some weird quirks like that. Thanks for marking it the answer!